# Time Flow Chart in SSRS (2016)?

Tags: sql-server, time, reporting-services, process, flowchart

I am trying to create a report table in SSRS 2016 but I am not sure how to go about it or if it is possible.

I am trying to recreate something similar to that in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7F13.png) with hours from left to right with 3 timed processes illustrated on the table relevant to the time the process started ended. Is such a report table possible in SSRS?

The data I am using looks similar to that in image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dqTk.png).

I'm using the SQL Server 2016 sp1 package.

Comment: you can use a Tablix and handle the [TotalTime] on ssrs or sql server. I prefer sql server side as you only use ssrs to render what sql server throws at ssrs.

Comment: your sql server side tsql would look something along these lines....
select datediff(HOUR,'2018-11-01','2018-11-10')

Comment: Apologies @junketsu the image you saw was a data sample. Please look at image one again, It is the table I need to create. Apologies, my first post

Comment: plz make sure to read up about charts. Its not as simple as excel. As you do have to specify what goes on X and Y axis, etc. But will get you what your looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want that. Provided you have your sql query built in form of Stored proc or raw sql. Right click -> add chart -> choose the type you like.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, junketsu, that is the chart I wanted.